# ANTLR4: Parser adding duplicate entries

Tags: antlr4

I have below input to be parsed:-

```
([LANGUAGE] IN ("Arabic", "Dutch") AND [Content Series] IN ("The Walking Dead") AND [PUBLISHER_NAME] IN ("Yahoo Search", "Yahoo! NAR") )  

OR 

([LANGUAGE] IN ("English") AND [PUBLISHER_NAME] IN ("Aol News", "Microsoft-Bing!") )
```

Basically the inputs have 2 groups separated by 'OR'.Both groups has several base exp(targetEntities) separated by AND. So each group has list of target entities.

Grammar file:

```
grammar Exp;

options {
language = Java;
}

start
:  def EOF
;

def : (AND? base)+
|  (OR? '(' def ')')*
;

base : key operator values ;

key : LSQR ID RSQR ;

values : '('  VALUE   (','  VALUE)* ')'  ;

operator : IN
| NIN
;
VALUE:  '"' .*? '"' ;
AND : 'AND' ;
OR : 'OR' ;
NOT : 'not' ;
EQ : '=' ;
COMMA : ',' ;
SEMI : ';' ;
IN : 'IN' ;
NIN : 'NOT_IN' ;
LSQR : '[' ;
RSQR : ']' ;

INT : [0-9]+ ;
ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9-!]* ;
WS: [\t\n\r\f ]+ -> skip ;
```

Below is the listener and parser-

```
 @Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ANTLRTargetingExpressionParser {`

static List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
public String entityOperator;

public static class ExpMapper extends ExpBaseListener {
TargetEntity targetEntity;
Group group;
List<TargetEntity> targetEntities;
private static int inc = 1;

    @Override
    public void exitDef(ExpParser.DefContext ctx) {
    group.setTargets(targetEntities);
    groupList.add(group);
    super.exitDef(ctx);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void exitValues(ExpParser.ValuesContext ctx) {
      targetEntity.setValues(
          Arrays.asList(
              Arrays.toString(ctx.VALUE().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()).toArray())));
      super.exitValues(ctx);
      targetEntities.add(targetEntity);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void exitOperator(ExpParser.OperatorContext ctx) {
      targetEntity.setOperator(ctx.getText());
      super.exitOperator(ctx);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void exitKey(ExpParser.KeyContext ctx) {
      targetEntity = new TargetEntity();
      ctx.getParent();
      targetEntity.setEntity(ctx.ID().getText());
      super.exitKey(ctx);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void enterDef(ExpParser.DefContext ctx) {
      group = new Group();
      targetEntities = new ArrayList<>();
      super.enterDef(ctx);
    }

}

public List<Group> parse(String expression) {`

    ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(expression);
    ExpLexer lexer = new ExpLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    ExpParser parser = new ExpParser(tokens);
    parser.setBuildParseTree(true); // tell ANTLR to build a parse tree
    ParseTree tree = parser.def();
    
    /** Create standard walker. */
    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
    ExpMapper mapper = new ExpMapper();
    walker.walk(mapper, tree);
    
    return groupList;

}
}
```

Output:-

```
[Group(targets=[{LANGUAGE, IN, [["Dutch", "Arabic"]]}, {Content_Series, IN, [["The Walking Dead"]]}, {PUBLISHER_NAME, IN, [["Yahoo Search", "Yahoo! NAR"]]}]),  
Group(targets=[{LANGUAGE, IN, [["English"]]}, {PUBLISHER_NAME, IN, [["Aol News", "Microsoft-Bing!"]]}]),  
Group(targets=[{LANGUAGE, IN, [["English"]]}, {PUBLISHER_NAME, IN, [["Aol News", "Microsoft-Bing!"]]}])]
```

Q1:- I am getting duplicate value in the grouplist at end. Tried checking the value in ctx to stop the walker but couldnt help.
Q2:- Also how can we  catch the soft exception thrown by grammar file in case of wrong input given in java.

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: It's MUCH easier to sort questions out if you ensure that the examples you provide are valid and are compilable.  I had to change a few things just to get a clean parse, and there's too much missing to attempt to compile and run your code.)

That said....

```
def : (AND? base)+
|  (OR? '(' def ')')*
;
```

Would normally be represented as something akin to

```
def: '(' def ')'
   | def AND def
   | def OR def
   | base
   ;
```

(Note: these are not exactly equivalent.  Your rule requires parentheses around `def`s used in an `OR`, but disallows them when used with `AND`.  Those would be "odd" constraints, so I'm not sure if you intended that.)

You'll notice here that it's clear that a `def` can contain other `def`s.  This is also true in your rule for (but only as the second half of an `OR` type.

It can be really useful to use a plugin or the `-gui` option of the antler tool, to see a visual representation of your tree.  (Both IntelliJ, and VS Code have good plugins available for this).  With that visualization it would have been clear that there was a `def` in a subtree of a `def`.  (The information would have been the in the output of the `System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));`, but a bit harder to notice.

This is your clue.  You're getting a duplicate of the second half of your `OR` and this is because you'll have a nested `def` and, as a result, you'll `exitDef` twice (and add it twice in the process).

Your listener does not handle nested structures like this properly (having only a `targetEntity` and a `group`).  You'll need to do something like maintaining a stack of `Group` instances and pushing/popping as you enter/exit (and only dealing with the top of the stack).

A few other observations:

```
super.enterDef(ctx);
```

There's no need to call the `super` method on your listener overrides, the default methods are empty.  (Of course, it does no harm, and it can be a "safe" practice to generally call the `super` method when overriding.

```
ctx.getParent();
```

You didn't do anything with this `parent`, as a result, this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your observation and yes this is intended to have nested def . I had looked into the tree using gui and it seems to be correct. Issue which I see while walking it is that only last base separated by AND is getting repeated. I am quiet new to ANTLR and still learning . Not sure if I am able to explain better. I tried editing question too with few more details.

Comment: This is not really an ANTLR thing.  There's not enough information in your question to infer what your resulting data structure *should* be, but it seems clear that it's incapable to representing the recursive nature of the `AND` and `OR` alternatives of your `def` rule.  (Take a look at the graphical tree; you'll need to account for a `Group` that is just a `base`, a `Group` that is an AND of two `Groups, and a Group that is an OR of two `Group`s.    You'll then need to manage a stack of the `Group`s that are in the process of being evaluated and build the correct type of `Group` as you exit

Comment: Note: you may also benefit from using labelled alternatives on your `def` rule.